# PowerShell pass arguments with quotes

Tags: powershell

Have very useful script named `sudo.ps1`:

```
$w=""; foreach($a in $args[1..($args.length-1)] ){ $w += " " + $a }; $w
Start-Process $args[0] -ArgumentList $w -Verb RunAs -Wait
```

but it can't handle complex command

```
./sudo.ps1 schtasks /create /F /TN "$vpn_name Connection Update" /TR "Powershell.exe -noexit -command D:\vpn-route.ps1" /SC ONEVENT /EC Application /MO "*[System[(Level=4 or Level=0) and (EventID=20225)]] and *[EventData[Data='$vpn_name']]" /RL HIGHEST
```

Problem is in obfuscated quotes. In `sudo.ps1` quotes are opened:

```
 /create /F /TN VPN-Kosmos6 Connection Update /TR Powershell.exe -noexit -command D:\vpn-route.ps1 /SC ONEVENT /EC Application /MO *[System[(Level=4 or Level=0) and (EventID=20225)]] and *[EventData[Data='VPN-Kosmos6']] /RL HIGHEST
```

Command executed with no error, but does no work. How can it be fixed?

Comment: Quotes are not part of string literal value and `Start-Process` does not add quotes by itself. If you want quotes, then you should include them into string, like so: `"""$vpn_name Connection Update"""`.

Comment: For a bit more robust implementation checkout Invoke-Elevated (alias su) at line 466 here - https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx/blob/master/Src/Pscx/Modules/Utility/Pscx.Utility.psm1

Comment: Don't try so hard to get all of the quoting correct. See this article for some tips. [Windows IT Pro: Running Executables in PowerShell](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/running-executables-powershell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If arg contains space, add quotes via `"""` *(thanks to [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446816/powershell-pass-arguments-with-quotes#comment54681908_33446816))*. Now `sudo.ps1` works fine:

```
$w=""; foreach($a in $args[1..($args.length-1)] ){ $w+=" "; if($a -match " "){$w+="""$a"""}else{$w+=$a} }; $w
Start-Process $args[0] -ArgumentList $w -Verb RunAs -Wait
```

Consider another solutions suggested by [Keith Hill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446816/powershell-pass-arguments-with-quotes#comment54683537_33446816) and [Bill_Stewart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446816/powershell-pass-arguments-with-quotes#comment54688879_33446816), if looking for better and more complex decision.